# fontawesome adding element styling

Tags: css, font-awesome

When I add `font-family: FontAwesome;` to my css it adds the following to my styles:

```
element.style {
border-bottom-width: 7px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: red;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Here is my stylesheet:

```
.addfavorite {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

.star {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px!important;
}

.addfavorite span.star:before {
    content: "\f006";
    color: #999999;
}

.addfavorite span.star:hover:before, .addfavorite span.star:hover~span.star:before {
    content: "\f005";
    color: #e3cf7a;
}
```

When I remove `font-family: FontAwesome;` the style goes away, but of course, I lose my star.

I have added `border-bottom-width: 0px!important` as a temporary fix, but dont like the fact that its still 'there'.

Html is as follows:

```
<div class="addfavorite"><span class="star"></span> Add To Favorites</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need FontAwesome? There are so many stars available otherwise! `\22C6`, `\2605` and `\2606`, `\2729` through `\274B` etc.

Comment: I need the outline and the filled version.  I'll check them out. I was planning on utilizing some other features though.